# Get Count of entries in all tables in database using django

Tags: django

Without mentioning the tables can i get count of entries in each table using django ORM.
Don't want to use count() against each table manually.
Database in use in MySQL

Comment: That is specific towards the database used. Some databases have a table that contains the tables (with approximation of the number of elements).

Comment: Using mysql for the project. I have the sql query that gives the output. Looking if the same is possible using Django

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a table named `information_schema.tables` that contains the tables as records, and has `table_rows`.

You can make a non-managed model and then filter with:

```
class Table(models.Model):
    table_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    table_rows = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'information_schema.tables'
```

We can then obtain the number of records for `User` and `Group` for example with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User

Table.objects.filter(table_name__in=[User._meta.db_table, Group._meta.db_table])
```

By subclassing the `CharField` for the `table_name` field, we could even make the interface more convenient.

The main advantage is that you can fetch the counts in "bulk": retrieving the count of for example twenty models, without the need to perform twenty queries.